# Adding multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add multiple text inputs, but how? Just putting the number of inputs I want on screen is the only input that I have declared in HTML.

Let's say that I type the number `3` then when I press the button. The number of inputs I entered should appear. It actually only adds one input per click and ignores the typed data in the input. How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML</title>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
<body>          
    <input type="text" id="inp1" name="inp1" placeholder="Number of inputs">    
    <button type="button" name="btn" id="btn">Add</button>

    <table id="table" name="table">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {    
        $('#table tbody').append('<input></input>')
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that you cannot just append an `input` as a child of a `tbody`. You need to place it within a `td`, which in turn needs to be in a `tr`. Also note that `input` is self closing, so you should append only `<input />`.

To achieve what you need you can use a simple `for` loop, using the entered value as the iteration limiter (once you've parsed it to an integer). Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($('#inp1').val(), 10); i++) {
      $('#table tbody td').append('<input />')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp1" name="inp1" placeholder="Number of inputs">
<button type="button" name="btn" id="btn">Add</button>

<table id="table" name="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank u so much. I'm just learning, still taking baby steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#btn").on("click",function(){
        
        var number = $("#inp1").val();
        
        number = parseFloat(number);
        
        for (var i=1; i <= number; i++){
            
            $("#table tbody").append("<br>Number " + i + " : <input type=text><br>")
            
        }
        
    })
    
    
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp1" name="inp1" placeholder="Number of inputs">  

<button type="button" name="btn" id="btn">Add</button>
<table id="table" name="table">
        <tbody></tbody>
</table>    
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I really appreciate it.