# codeigniter upload multiple pdf files error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-3

I have a simple page with a script for posting multiple files to be uploaded on a webserver.

```
?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

but I'm trying a lot of solution to change this code that work only if I post 1 file

```
public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    echo "error";
            }
            else
            {
                    echo "upload success";
            }
}
```

Can anyone can help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
name=userfile[]
```

if you want to add multiple form, you can try this :

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i <=5 ; $i++) :?>
     <input type="file" name="userfile<?php echo $i;?>"><br/>
<?php endfor;?>
```

and add this to the controller :

```
   for ($i=1; $i <=5 ; $i++) { 
       if(!empty($_FILES['userfile'.$i]['name'])){
           if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'.$i))
               $this->upload->display_errors();  
           else
               echo "file berhasil di upload";
       }
   }
```

hope this can help you

Comment: thanks for reply
the files are dinamically  not 5 or less

Comment: I see,
maybe you can using javascript for this problem

try to create the button for add more file, then using javascript for show more input type, so the input file is dinamic now

you can use validation for this.
maybe this one can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808666/11857396